# Real interpolation space between the Wiener algebra and $L^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fourier-transform, interpolation-spaces, besov-spaces

The Wiener algebra $W_n$ is the image by the Fourier transform of $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$. What is the (complex) interpolation space between $W_n$ and $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$? It is probably not true that for $\theta \in (0,1)$,
$$
[W_n, L^2(\mathbb R^n)]_\theta = L^p(\mathbb R^n),\quad p=2/\theta,
$$
but the homogeneity required should be the right one. Are some Besov spaces better candidates?

Comment: Do you mean complex interpolation? (the real interpolation has two parameters).

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Yes, you are right. But some real interpolation result would also be interesting to me.